# How to make hyperlink to a specific page in jasper report?

Tags: java, hyperlink, jasper-reports, jasperserver

I have a jrxml file. In this file I have a column with hyperlink to same report. But when I click on this link from any page jasper server loads first page. How can I load the same page from which I clicked on the link?
 Here is the example jrxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="report2" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="a5de7f4f-53e0-43ce-a41d-cd01ab98e889">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[SELECT * from employee]]>
    </queryString>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="35" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="61" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement x="21" y="41" width="110" height="20" uuid="ac484988-9581-4b7e-bf5d-2585ae2a1365"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[($F(roll_no))]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <image hAlign="Center" hyperlinkType="ReportExecution">
                <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="481" y="41" width="20" height="20" uuid="5a15a90d-499d-47ed-a768-4f703c6c5ed4"/>
                <imageExpression><![CDATA["/datasources/Images/check"]]></imageExpression>
                <hyperlinkParameter name="_report">
                    <hyperlinkParameterExpression><![CDATA["/root/reports/myReport"]]></hyperlinkParameterExpression>
                </hyperlinkParameter>
            </image>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="463" y="23" width="65" height="18" uuid="f13d3810-4106-42d8-acdc-0eeb8033cd32"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font size="12" isBold="true" isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Accept]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="21" y="23" width="110" height="18" uuid="fbb887ce-fab7-4142-8de2-f7f565e1bb18"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Staus]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="125" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band height="45" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="54" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height="42" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: Add some code or explain with example

Comment: Added example jrxml data in question

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an anchor to the points in your report you want to be able to jump to, and specify these in your hyperlink definitions.
Cannot post an example but this should be enough info to get you started if you're using iReport or Jaspersoft Studio to author your reports.

Comment: We can create anchor to part of report but Here I want jump to page.

Comment: How about creating an anchor placed page header, using a varible which is incremented for each page ?

Comment: I am not using page header. After adding band in page header I tried to add anchor but did not find hyperlink option in that.